# How to align code, in PhpStorm / Intellij, using tabs (and not spaces)

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to setup PhpStorm, so I can simply press: "Reformat Code" ( <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>), before each save - and then it'll make everything look right.

But I have this case, where I don't know how to make PhpStorm make the code right.

This is the code:

[image: Wrong aligning character]

As you can see, then *indentation* is with tabs, but the aligning of the characters are with spaces.

I want it to look like this:

[image: Right aligning character]

It would be cool to get the solution. But it would be even cooler to be able to figure out, how I could have found the solution myself.

**Further info / idea:** There is a [Php Codesniffer from Squizlabs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) implemented. So I can fix is automatically by running a `sniff fix`-command. It would be pretty cool, to be able to automatically setup PhpStorm's Code style settings, to correspond with Squizlabs styles, without having to gradually tune the settings one thing at the time. But I haven't found that functionality.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Read through all `Settings >> Editor >> Code style >> PHP`

I couldn't find anything that resembled this.

### Solution attempt 2: Disable `.editorconfig`

I've read quite a bit about `.editorconfig` and it doesn't have these nitty-gritty functions here (as aligning equal signs).

But to make sure, I tried disabling it. Didn't make a difference.

### Solution attempt 3: Search setting for 'align' and 'formatting'

But I didn't find anything useful. :-/

### Solution attempt 4: Update PhpStorm

I was on PhpStorm version `2022.2.1`.
I tried updating to PhpStorm version `2022.2.4`.

This is still in progress.

Comment: Please show what you have at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | PHP`, specifically `Tabs and Indents` tab. Checking `Use tab character` option with **unchecked** `Smart tabs` should do that.

Comment: NOTE that there are some cases where Tabs cannot be used (e.g. aligning multiple array entries on value (Space symbols before `=>` on your screenshot). It may sound obvious "why not", but some want to see tabs used there as well.

Comment: *"Solution attempt 2: Disable .editorconfig"* As long as it has `indent_style = tab`  the IDE should use tabs. But disabling is a right way for troubleshooting as settings from such file takes over the corresponding IDE settings.

Comment: It was the `Smart tabs`-setting that I should remove. Thinking about it now, I wasn't sure what it did, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956673/1766219). So it makes sense that that was the culprit. 

Thanks again, @LazyOne ! If you write your comment as an answer, then I can mark it as the solution. <3

Comment: *"I've read quite a bit about `.editorconfig` and it doesn't have these nitty-gritty functions here (as aligning equal signs)."* Yes and No at the same time: **Yes** -- it does not have anything special for detailed formatting (at all), only the most general settings. But **No** -- you can export (or manually write) IDE code style settings there and IDE will use them. Just start typing with `ij_` in such a file and the IDE will offer a completion help. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show what you have at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | PHP`, specifically `Tabs and Indents` tab.

Checking `Use tab character` option with *unchecked* `Smart tabs` should do just that.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.3/settings-code-style-php.html#php-specific-formatting-settings-for-tabs-and-indents

[image: PhpStorm Code Style | Tabs and Indents]
(*Pro tip: you can copy-paste your code sample in the preview area and start changing the options; the IDE will apply the changes live on the provided code sample instead of the default one.*)